# java.lang.ArrayStoreException when extending a list with new elements

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am calling methods with parameters like this: `methodName(Object... param)`. These methods I can't change. To keep my code a bit more dynamic, I have lists which I pass to these methods. On its own, this is no issue, as I can call:

```
methodName(list.toArray(new Object[]{}));
```

and it works just fine. However, I sometimes need to pass additional elements to these methods, but can't add these items to the list. For this I tried the following:

```
methodName(Arrays.asList(list, oobj1, obj2).toArray(new Object[]{}));
```

which compiles just fine. But when calling this, it results in an `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

Below is an example code which replicates exactly this behavior. I have attempted multiple variations, but none work as expected.

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
nums.add(1);
nums.add(2);
nums.add(3);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(nums, 8, 9).toArray(new Integer[] {}));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(nums.toArray(new Integer[] {}), 8, 9).toArray(new Integer[] {}));
```

`Arrays.asList(nums, 8, 9)` alone results in `[[1, 2, 3], 8, 9]` and `Arrays.asList(nums.toArray(new Integer[] {}), 8, 9)` results in `[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@15db9742, 8, 9]`.

The desired output is `[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]` without too much more code. How can I achieve this while keeping the initial list intact?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it in the method call itself and not create another duplication of the list before and add the elements to it? Also it’s look like you missed the point of the … in Java, it’s to allow you to pass multiple parameters to the function, not just a list of all of them. If you want to stick with the list I’ll recommend changing the function signature to a list<Object> or something like this.

Comment: I think you're better off using a utility function (either your own or from a library). You'd need a lot of extra code to be able to do this inline.

Comment: @SgtOmer As stated in the question, I can't change the method signature. Also I am well aware of how `...` works in Java, as I am trying to utilize it right now. The issue is just that the parameters I need to pass in is dynamic. For that reason I create the list, and want to pass it into the method together with some fixed parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sweeper suggested, I implemented an utility function.

The code is now

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    nums.add(1);
    nums.add(2);
    nums.add(3);
    System.out.println(concat(7, nums, 4, 5, 6));
}
private <T> List<T> concat(T... nums) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : nums) {
        if (t instanceof Collection)
            result.addAll((Collection<? extends T>) t);
        else
            result.add(t);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am not going for recursion in my code base as I know that I won't be nesting another list within `nums`. However, recursion can be easily implemented as well, and the call wouldn't even change:

```
static <T> List<T> concat(T... nums) {
    return concat(new ArrayList<>(), nums);
}

static <T> List<T> concat(List<T> result, T... nums) {
    for (T t : nums) {
        if (t instanceof Collection)
            concat(result, ((Collection<T>) t).toArray((T[]) new Object[] {}));
        else
            result.add(t);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Overall the advantage of this concat method, is the fact that you can prepend and append at the same time. You can even concatenate multiple lists and also add elements between the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to do it (added correct flatMap approach by SgtOmer):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ArrayStore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        nums.add(1);
        nums.add(2);
        nums.add(3);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            Stream.concat(nums.stream(), IntStream.of(8, 9).boxed()).toArray(Integer[]::new)
        ));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            Stream.concat(nums.stream(), Stream.of(new Integer[]{8, 9})).toArray(Integer[]::new)
        ));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
            Arrays.asList(nums, Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{8, 9})).stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).toArray(Integer[]::new)
        ));
    }
}
```

produces

```
$ java ArrayStore.java
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this is what you were looking for:

```
Arrays.asList(mums, [8, 9]).stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(<the collector you want>)
```

Comment: This does not even compile

Comment: You need to fill a collector of your desire

Comment: `Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList(mums, 8, 9))` this does not compile

Comment: Sorry, missed it, fixed it now

Comment: Still not compiling... `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`

Comment: Forgot to add the elements as array for the flatmap. Sorry doing it from my phone

Comment: Even less valid java. You should be sure that your answer works before posting...